# READ statement doesn't read last number from file

Tags: matrix, fortran

Suppose you have this program

1. Subroutine `readDIM` which reads the dimensions (rows, columns) of a matrix from a txt file. (In order to simplify, let it be an INTEGER). `ReadDIM` works using tokens and it works fine by assumption.

A text file containing for example:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 20 5
3 0 333 3
```

Returns `nrow = 3, ncol = 4`

2. Since `readDIM` has given the true dimensions of the matrix, I want to allocate space to:

   ```
   REAL, DIMENSION (:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: vMatrix
   ```

To read the matrix from a txt file and to store it into the 2d-array. So I've written the following

```
SUBROUTINE buildVMatrix     
   OPEN(UNIT=1, FILE = filename, STATUS ='OLD',IOSTAT=ios);
   ALLOCATE(vMatrix(nrow,ncol));
   WRITE(*,*) "Register matrix from file:", filename;
   WRITE(*,*) "-------------------------------------------------------";
   DO i = 1, UBOUND(vMatrix,1)
      READ(1,*, IOSTAT = ios) (vMatrix(i,j),j=1,UBOUND(vMatrix,2));
      !IF(ios /= 0 ) EXIT 
   END DO
   CLOSE(1)
END SUBROUTINE
```

When I print `vMatrix` the output is:

```
matrix.txt   : 1 2 3 4            buildVMatrix output (once printed) 1 2 3 4
               1 2 20 5                                              1 2 20 5    
               3 0 333 3                                             3 0 333 0
```

It doesn't read the last number. I know it's caused by the `DO` loop inside `buildVMatrix`, but can't explain myself this and have no idea how to fix it writing a different code.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this after copying your subroutine verbatim.

Comment: Isn't unit number 1 reserved? I usually use quite a high number.

Comment: I concur with @KyleKanos, I cannot reproduce your error. The exact code I am using is here: http://pastebin.com/ewsKELZT

Comment: maybe your error is in printing it? please post entire code to reproduce.

Comment: Do you have a newline character after your last number or does the file immediately end after the last number without newline? If it is the latter, try to add a newline after the last number.

Comment: First, thank you for answering. I solved this replacing the UBOUND() functions with nrow and ncol variables. I've made that basing on the consideration that follows: readDIM reads the number of elements on the first line to calculate ncol and starts reading until the end of file to get the nrow, but it's very sensible to any space placed on blank records, so I had noticed that it was counting 1 more line than expected, but it was empty. Furthermore I've modified in some way the print subroutine to ensure that only matrix-reading errors would have happened.

Answer (score 0):

It's because there's no line ending at the last line in your txt file, try to type a return after the last number.